# qmake's write_file() and system() doesn't want to make a file

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

I've got a strange behavior of qmake while trying to write smth to another file. I read all possible manuals and searched out the internet but found nothing similiar. Closer to the simplest possible code:

```
!system(echo 1 > d:\1.txt) {
  warning(Cant create a file)
}
```

It doesn't create a file, and it doesn't show a warning, that means that operation succeded. Another example:

```
var = test string
file = $$absolute_path(d:\1.txt)
message(Variable: $$var and filename: $$file)
!write_file($$pathBat, pathtowrite) {
  warning(Cant create a file)
}
```

This block produces output:
`Project MESSAGE: Variable: test string and filename: d:/1.txt`

And nothing is said about the fact the file has *not* been created.

I've already checked the rights to write to the directory: everything seems fine.

Can anybody help me with this?

**UPD:**
I've found something else: `message($$system(echo 1 > 1.txt))` works fine. And this is what makes me cry, because I really don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Open a command prompt, `cd`  to your build directory, and type in `echo 1 > d:\1.txt` - did it work?

Comment: Yes, of course it works. It works not even just to d:\1.txt, but also to the current directory: `echo 1 > 1.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huh! I found the solution and it may sounds like *buy yourself some brain*. I thought, that `qmake` is launched every time the project file is changed (output of `message` commands proved my thoughts), but it's not really the way things happen in Qt.

I don't know how exactly, but it parses the *.pro* file, does only some necessary operations, and as I can see `system()` (which is going to change some file), `write_file()` commands doesn't seem to be invoked.

The **SOLUTION** is so much simple: natively launch qmake using the `Build - Launch qmake`.